# Why GLSL "optimizing" this shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have simple shader where I trying to apply scaling and rotation onto model's coordinates

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 VertexUV;

out VS_GS_VERTEX
{
    vec3 vs_worldpos;
    vec3 vs_normal;
    vec2 VertexUV;
} vertex_out;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 lookAtMatrix;
uniform mat4 mdlScaleMatrix;
uniform mat4 mdlRotMatrix;

void main(void)
{
    mat4 mdlMat = mdlRotMatrix * mdlScaleMatrix;
    vec4 mdlPos = mdlMat * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);

    mat4 MVP = projectionMatrix * lookAtMatrix * modelMatrix;

    gl_Position = MVP * mdlPos;
    gl_Normal = mat3(modelMatrix) * VertexNormal;

    vertex_out.vs_worldpos = gl_Position.xyz;
    vertex_out.vs_normal = gl_Normal;
    vertex_out.VertexUV = VertexUV;
}
```

but for some reason `glGetUniformLocation` for `mdlRotMatrix` and `mdlScaleMatrix` returns `-1`. I can see values 4-6 for other uniforms. Why it happens? I checked names and copy-pasted several times, made error in code to check and got compilation error (shader works with exact file), so names and shader are intact.

Comment: I guess, some hardware may have very limited number of uniform variables that can be defined. BTW, why do you do matrix calculations on uniforms in shader? This is not efficient - it will do it on each vertex. (but if you understand it and will optimize later - it's OK)

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you put those uniforms at the top?  IE: the bottom 2 uniforms are null no matter what the bottom 2 are.  I don't know why it would be running out of uniform space for so few variables.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: GLSL does impose this sort of limitation, but GLSL 330 guarantees a minimum of 1024 uniform components in a vertex shader - these 4x4 matrices have 16 components each so he should not be approaching any hardware/implementation limit in a compliant system.

Comment: I tried to move uniforms up, same. It seems position returned depends from some sort of register assigned. By resorting uniforms I still have same values assigned to locations. Had same effect with `-1` when uniforms not used in code. But here they suppose to be used.

Comment: Right now also fragment shader used (geometry skipped) and fragment shader receives this vertex_out. Code works, except I decided to add 2 more uniforms and 2 lines with model stuff.

Comment: "This is not efficient - it will do it on each vertex" - thanks for hint (was not sure, learning) optimization later.

Comment: vec3 light_direction = normalize(light_position - vertex_in.vs_worldpos);
 vec3 normal = normalize(vertex_in.vs_normal);
 vec3 half_vector = normalize(light_direction + normalize(vertex_in.vs_worldpos));
 - code from fragment shader.

Comment: Uh oh, problem solved, for some mistake shader program id for models was the same as for terrain ...